# Connecting All Nodes Together on a Graph

Tags: r, data-visualization, igraph

I have the following network graph:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)


set.seed(123)
n=5
data = tibble(d = paste(1:n))

relations = data.frame(tibble(
  from = sample(data$d),
  to = lead(from, default=from[1]),
))

graph = graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=T, vertices = data) 

V(graph)$color <- ifelse(data$d == relations$from[1], "red", "orange")

plot(graph, layout=layout.circle, edge.arrow.size = 0.2)
```

[image]

I want to connect each Node to every Node on this graph - I can do this manually by redefining the "relations" data frame:

```
relations_1 = data.frame("from" = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5), "to" = c(2,3,4,5,1,3,4,5,1,2,4,5,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,4))
```

Then, I can re-run the network graph:

```
graph = graph_from_data_frame(relations_1, directed=T, vertices = data) 

V(graph)$color <- ifelse(data$d == relations_1$from[1], "red", "orange")

plot(graph, layout=layout.circle, edge.arrow.size = 0.2)
```

[image]

- But would there have been a way to "automatically" connect all the points in the graph directly using the "relations" data frame without manually creating a new data frame "relations_1"? Could a single line (or a few lines) of code have been added that would have automatically taken the "relations" data frame and connected everything together?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just update `relations` using `complete`, and than filter out the rows where `from` is equal to `to`, which gives arrows from a node to itself.

```
relations <- relations %>% 
  complete(from, to) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(from != to)
```

Answer (score 2):

An solution using `igraph::make_full_graph`:

```r
relations %>%
  with(union(from,to)) %>%
  {
    G <- make_full_graph(length(.), directed = TRUE)
    V(G)$name <- .
    G
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you depart from `graph`, you can try the following code using `add_edges` + `get.adjacency`

```
graph %>%
    add_edges(c(t(which(`diag<-`(get.adjacency(., sparse = FALSE), 1) != 1, arr.ind = TRUE))))
```

which adds all missing edges while retaining the attributes from your original `graph` object, and you will see

[image]